# Match character from string with binary list

Tags: python

With string `abcdefg` and list `[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]`, what is a Pythonic way to return all characters in the string that match `1 (on)` in the list?

The desired output will be:

```
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f']
```

Thanks!

**Edit:**

One more question, is it possible to group `ab` and `ef` so that the output will look something like this: `['ab', 'ef']`? Basically the idea is to group characters that are separated by `0`. If no `0` then it'll be `['abcdefg']`. Thanks!

Comment: Answers are in multiple styles. I guess none of us are Dutch. "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [itertools.compress](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) for this purpose

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> list(compress("abcdefg", [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]))
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f']
```

If you do not want to import any modules, you can also use

```
>>> [e for e, i in zip("abcdefg", [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]) if i]
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f']
```

Based on your latest requirement

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> st = "abcdefghijklm"
>>> some_list = [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]
>>> it_l = iter(some_list)
>>> [''.join(v) for k, v in groupby(st, key = lambda e:next(it_l)) if k]
['ab', 'fgh', 'l']
```

or better

```
>>> [''.join(zip(*v)[-1]) for k, v in groupby(zip(some_list, st), key = itemgetter(0)) if k]
['ab', 'fgh', 'l']
```

Comment: is it possible to separate `ab` and `ef` so that the output will look something like this: `['ab', 'ef']`? thanks!

Comment: @Rock how is that `separating`? It looks like `joining` to me. It'd also help if you were more explicit - what would the output be for  `['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'g']` for instance?

Comment: @JonClements: wording stuff. my intention is to `group` all characters that are separated by `0`. in your example, the output'll be `['abcdefg']`.

Comment: @Rock: See the update in the answer. Next time please be clear with your requirement, or ask a new question

Comment: @Abhijit: I know. Since it's based on the same question, I didn't want to start a new one. I'll be clear next time.

Answer (score 2):

```
[x[0] for x in zip("abcdefg", [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]) if x[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Three solutions:

```
s = 'abcdefg'
li = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

print [c for i,c in enumerate(s) if li[i]]

print [s[i] for i,b in enumerate(li) if b]

it = iter(li)
print [c for c in s if it.next()]
```

My prefered one is the one with iter() : no zip, no enumerate, no itertool

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your update - you an use `itertools.groupby` to identify runs of consecutive values, and build a list from that - eg:

```
text = 'abcdefg'
bits = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

from itertools import groupby
print [''.join(el[0] for el in g) for k, g in groupby(zip(text, bits), lambda L: L[1]) if k]
# ['ab', 'ef']
```