# Format string by binary list

Tags: python

With a string and a binary list of the same length, for example:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 s  t  a  c  k  o  v  e  r  f  l  o  w
```

Is it possible to obtain a new string as `-t-c-over----` that follows:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 -  t  -  c  -  o  v  e  r  -  -  -  -
```

That is, each character matching with `0` will be replaced as `-`. The desired output would be a list as below with letters matching `1` and hyphens matching `0` are grouped separately:

```
['-', 't', '-', 'c', '-', 'over', '----']
```

Thanks!

Comment: Neat little problem.  What have you tried?

Comment: @mgilson: Extracting letters matching `1` would be trivial but I have trouble replacing `0`.

Comment: @Rock: Do you know how to iterate two sequences in lock step?

Comment: @abarnert: not sure. I guess using `zip`, right?

Comment: Exactly. What happens if you `zip` your string and binary list together? And then do, say, a `for` loop iterating over the result?

Comment: @Rock -- Give it a try and update your post if it doesn't work.  If we're still around tonight, abarnert or I will take a look at it and help you out.  (If you do get it working, post it as an answer :).  Then let us know -- we'd love to take a look at it (or at least I would :))

Comment: @mgilson: A similar question was already answered a day ago, which required a slight modification. In regards to that, this Question may not have deserved such upvotes :-)

Comment: @Abhijit: this is by your suggestion to open a new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have fun with iterators (no zip needed! :)

```
it = iter([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
s = 'stackoverflow'

output = [''.join(('-' for i in b) if not a else b)
          for a,b in 
          itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x: next(it))]
```

So output will be:

```
['-', 't', '-', 'c', '-', 'over', '----']
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this?
Zip the two lists and iterate and build the output. Keep the last binary value to determine whether you should append or concat.

```
blist = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
string = 'stackoverflow'
output = []    
previous = not blist[0] # to cause the first char to be appended

for b,s in zip(blist, string):
    char = '-' if b == 0 else s

    if previous == b:
        output[-1] += char         
    else:
        output.append(char)

    previous = b

print(output)
```

Another option is regex:

```
import re

blist = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
string = 'stackoverflow'

x = ''.join(['-' if b == 0 else s for b,s in zip(blist, string)])
output = re.findall('(-+|[a-z]+)', x)

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15151027/977038) to your [last Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151011/match-character-from-string-with-binary-list) could have been slightly modified to get the desired result

First Answer:

Given

```
[''.join(v) for k, v in groupby(st, key = lambda e:next(it_lst))]
```

Modified

```
[''.join(v if k else ('-' for _ in v)) 
 for k, v in groupby(st, key = lambda e:next(it_lst))]
```

Second Answer

Given

```
[''.join(zip(*v)[-1]) 
 for k, v in groupby(zip(lst, st), key = itemgetter(0)) if k]
```

Modified

```
[''.join(zip(*v)[-1] if k else ('-' for _ in v)) 
 for k, v in groupby(zip(lst, st), key = itemgetter(0))]
```

**Note**
All you need to do is to

1. Stop ignoring the `0` entries
2. For Each `0` entries create a string of length equal to the grouped string under `0`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
string = "stackoverflow"
arr = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0]
new = ""
for i in range(len(arr)):
    new += string[i]*arr[i] +"-"*(abs(arr[i]-1))
```

this exploits that a string times 0 is an empty string.

Then you could split it up into a list of strings using regex

```
import re
list = re.findall("-+|[A-z]+", new)
```

the `"-+|[A-z]+"` matches patterns that are either a string of dashes of length more than 1 or a string of letters of length more than 1.