# From string to binary list

Tags: python

This is an extension to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169663/format-string-by-binary-list) but in a reversed order: that is, with string `-t-c-over----`, is there a way to generate a binary list that all valid letters have `1` and hyphens have `0`:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 -  t  -  c  -  o  v  e  r  -  -  -  -
```

I feel sorry for the back and forth but it has to go like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> s = '-t-c-over----'
>>> lst = [0 if i == '-' else 1 for i in s]
>>> print lst
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The list comp checks if a letter is `'-'` - if it is, it puts a `0` in the list, otherwise it puts a `1` in.

Comment: Thanks. I was stuck with iterators but forgot this simple way.

Comment: @Abhijit well I must admit your's was an interesting approach `;)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
string = "-t-c-over----"
[0 if i == "-" else 1 for i in string]

Output: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Your answer adds nothing new and refrain from naming a variable something form built-in or the standard library

Comment: I am really sorry but when I had clicked on post answer no answers were posted till then. But because of my internet problem it took too much time to get posted.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is use a lambda function and a map function.

```
s = '-t-c-over----'
output = map(lambda x: 0 if x == '-' else 1, s)
```

Edit: Apparently this doesn't work in Python 3.2 so the practical solution would be something like this.

```
s = '-t-c-over----'
output = [0 if x == '-' else 1 for x in s]
```

Comment: Depending of the python version, this doesn't necessarily create a list.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to which versions of python this wouldn't work?

Comment: For instance in python3.2. There output is a map object and not a list.